# Can't get requestFocus to focus on JTextFields sequentially

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield

I've been trying to make it so that when the `"Next"` button is clicked, it goes onto the next `JTextField` as required, and then the next, and next, and so on. It worked with only one `requestFocus()` but as *i* added that code to each of my `JTextFields` it instead goes straight to the last focus requested. Code below:

```
//adds functionality to the next button
        next.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //creates a file for the next button output
        final File file = new File("NextOutput.txt");
        //creates a printwriter to output to file everytime next button is clicked (overwrite)
        try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            String s = fName.getText();
            output.print(s + " ");
            lName.requestFocus();
            String s1 = lName.getText();
            output.append(s1 + " ");
            sNumber.requestFocus();
            String s2 = sNumber.getText();
            output.append(s2 + " ");
            lResults.requestFocus();
            String s3 = lResults.getText();
            output.append(s3 + " ");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyProgram.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

What is missing in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You've first to check which `TextField` is owning the focus, then, request the focus on the next field. In this approach, you are requesting the focus on `lName`, then on `sNumber`, then you will end up with `lResult` owning the focus.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //creates a file for the next button output
    final File file = new File("NextOutput.txt");
    //creates a printwriter to output to file everytime next button is clicked (overwrite)
    boolean lNameFocus = lName.isFocusOwner();
    boolean sNumberFocus = sNumber.isFocusOwner();
    boolean fNameFocus = fName.isFocusOwner();
    boolean lResultsFocus = lResults.isFocusOwner();

    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        //If none of the fields is owning the focus then lName requests the focus
        if (!(lNameFocus && sNumberFocus && fNameFocus && lResultsFocus)) {
            String s = fName.getText();
            output.print(s + " ");
            lName.requestFocus();
        //if lName is owning the focus then sNumber should be next to request
        } else if (lNameFocus) {
            String s1 = lName.getText();
            output.append(s1 + " ");
            sNumber.requestFocus();
        // and so on
        } else if (sNumberFocus) {
            String s2 = sNumber.getText();
            output.append(s2 + " ");
            lResults.requestFocus();
            String s3 = lResults.getText();
            output.append(s3 + " ");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyProgram.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```